# Combobox Dropdown Like An Image Gallery

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Combobox` where user can choose an icon. I'd like the dropdown to be displayed as a gallery.

So instead of showing each icon vertically in the dropdown like:

```
Combobox
   Image
   Image
   Image
   Image
   Image
   Image
   ...
```

I'd like the dropdown to be shown like:

```
Combobox
   Image Image Image Image
   Image Image Image Image
   Image Image Image Image
   Image Image Image Image
   ...
```

I tried doing:

```
<ComboBox Height="50" Width="60" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Icons}">
         <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400">
                        <Image Source="{Binding myImage, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

But that didn't seem to work, does anyone have any ideas how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work, though I haven't tried it with images:

```
<ComboBox Height="20" Width="100">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Width="150" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: One thing that took me a minute to figure out was that you now add items directly to the combo box rather than the wrap panel.  In hindsight this is obvious but me posting this might help someone

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<ComboBox Height="50" Width="60" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Icons}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <WrapPanel DataContext="{Binding}"  Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400">
                  <Image Source="{Binding myImage, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" Width="32" Height="32"/>
              </WrapPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I am assuming you have some property `myImage` in `Icons` representing something can will be converted to a `path` of `image` through your `converter`

I tried above code where `Icon` was `List<String>` where `string` was representing `path of image`

and I did this in XAML

```
<Image Source="{Binding}" Width="32" Height="32"/>
```

it worked fine for me