# ComboBox with Collection of Items shown but with only one selected

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am looking to create a type of ComboBox that will show it’s items as a Grid (like this question - [Combobox Dropdown Like An Image Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038995/combobox-dropdown-like-an-image-gallery))

But with an extra feature.

I need the entire “row” which has the selected item to be shown as the selected item in the box.

Can this be done by building on the mentioned question? Is a ComboBox even the right control to be using in the first place?

My first thoughts were to make the list of items that the ComboBox is bound to a list of smaller lists that contain the data set cut into chunks.

Before I go down this road I just wanted to run it past some fellow WPFers. I do hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Kris